# Password protect pages with prompt and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, password-protection

I am trying to password protect pages from a CMS I am using (couchcms). All the generated pages from the "contracts.php" page have a unique ID, and URL.

What I would like to do, is to have a prompt window to popup when the page loads if you visit one of these pages, and if what you enter doesn't match the contract ID of the URL you have visited, it would not allow the user to visit the page.

If the ID matches, then you can view the visited page.

For example:

Contract #334455 has the following URL :
example.com/contract/25348764329871098723498

If I would click on that link, I would see nothing but a blank page, and would see a prompt window. I would have to enter 334455 in the field to unlock the page. If not the right ID (that doesn't match with the current URL) it should show a message a block the page.

I tried something like this, but this isn't secure enough since you can see it in the source code, and it redirects to the same page, so it creates a loop and always ask for a password. I need it to just unlock the page, without redirecting :

```
 <SCRIPT>
function passwordCheck(){
    var password = prompt("Please enter the password.");
    if (password==="<cms:show my_uid/>"){
        window.location="<cms:show k_page_link/>";
    } else{
        while(password !=="<cms:show my_uid/>"){
            password = prompt("Please enter the password.");
        }
    }
}
window.onload=passwordCheck;
</SCRIPT>
```

Here's some details about the variables used :

```
<cms:show my_uid/> = The generated ID for the page
<cms:show k_page_link/> = The generated URL for the page
```

These variables changes for each pages.

Any solutions that would be more secure and would work like I described?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Security can only be achieved in an environment that only you control, hence it has to be implemented on the server and not on the client.

Comment: I understand. I just need something more secure than having the password directly in the source code. Doesn't need to be optimal, but just better than what I have described. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could do. Granted it is not the most secure but this is a simple bit of logic that is hidden from the source code:

```
**<?php
//All the verification stuff 
$password = "YOURPASSWORD";

function load_verify () { 
echo "<input type='password' name='txt_check' value='' style=' width: 300px; height: 30px; border-radius: 5px;' /> <br> ";
echo "<input type='submit' name='btn_check' value='Verify' style=' width: 300px;'  /> <br> <br> ";
} 

//check the password 
    if (isset($_POST['btn_check'])) {

    if ($password === $_POST['txt_check']){

         $_SESSION['is_verified'] = 1  ;

    }else {
        echo "Please Try Again <br>" ; 
        $_SESSION['is_verified'] = 0 ;
    }
    }

     $test = (isset($_SESSION['is_verified']))? 1:0 ; 

    //if password fails we reload the verify form if not we load the form and hide the verify 
    if ( $test === 1 && $_SESSION['is_verified'] === 1 ) {          
         load_form(); 

         $_SESSION['is_verified'] = 1  ;

    } else {    

            load_verify(); 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have pasted the code in my page, but all I see is the form being added to the top of the page, and I still see the rest. Also nothing happens if I click on the submit button.

Comment: You have to do all the work of loading your form in a function load_form(). That is where you load the rest of what will be your webpage.